# Windows 8.1 UI not updating when MVVM property set is called by UI element

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8.1

My problem is, that the UI isn't updating if they call the setter of the property which they binded to.
Here's a sample to make it clear:

Let's say I have a textbox binded to a property like this.

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="Task Name..." FontSize="24" 
         Text="{Binding TaskName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And this is my property:

```
public string TaskName
{
    get
    {
        return _taskName;
    }
    set
    {
        _taskName = "something";
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If I write something into the textbox then "something" should appear inside of it, after it loses focus, but there isn't any change. However, if I change the value of the property with code, like this:

```
TaskName = "something";
```

Then the change will appear on the UI as well.

Some further information.
This is how I implemented the INotifyPropertyChange interface:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static Navigator NavigationService;

    public static void SetNavigationService(Navigator service)
    {
        NavigationService = service;
    }

    protected void GoBack()
    {
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I really don't know why is it behave like this. I search for it for hours, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

in the setter of the property you need to call

```
RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.TaskName)
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted an older code, because I tried it really a lot of ways. So I call the RaisePropertyChanged like this RaisePropertyChanged( () => TaskName ). I checked with debug and the property name is get there as it should.

Comment: I debugged it with break point. When I write something into the TextBox then the setter is called. It even gets to the RaisePropertyChanged and call the event as well.

Comment: `Func<TResult>` doesn't take any argument anyway.